# Resolving private attributes in a derived class

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a base class `Circle` which has a `perimeter` function, and a derived class `Tire`. The following is the code:

```py
import math

class Circle(object):
    
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
    
    def area(self):
        p = self.__perimeter()
        return math.pi * (p *0.5/math.pi)**2 

    def perimeter(self):
        return self.__perimeter()
    
    def __perimeter(self):
        return 2.0 * math.pi * self.radius
```

And the class Tire:

```py
class Tire(Circle):
    def perimeter(self):
        return self.__perimeter()
    def __perimeter(self):
        return Circle.perimeter(self)*1.25
```

I know that any attribute with `__` in beginning is resolved to `_classname.__attribute`, so `__perimeter` in `Circle` would resolve to `_Circle.__perimeter`.

So if I run the following code, what would be the flow:

```py
t = Tire(20)
print(t.area())
```

What I believed was `t.area()` would call `self.__perimeter()` which would be resolved to `Tire._Tire__perimeter`, but that isn't compliant with the answer I got.

So basically it boils down to, how is `self` resolved?

Can someone please explain the flow behind this?

PS: This doubt is based on a presentation video by Raymond Hettinger.

Comment: A side note, there is no real need for `__perimeter`. Simply implement `perimeter` in each class according to its criteria

Answer (score 1):

The method `__perimeter` in the `Tire` class does not get called when you call `t.area()`, but calling the method `perimeter` in the class `Circle`. By this, you do not call `self.__perimeter()` (Beware of the **self** - it is has type *Tire* thus calling the tire perimeter method)

So when you call `t.area()` you do not access this via `t_Tire__perimeter()` - because this is how you would access the private perimeter function in the `Tire` class. (~157.079)
Which in code is basically:

```
t = Tire(20)
print(t.perimeter())
```

#### The flow is as so:

- Creating a new object of type `Tire` - which its superclass is `Circle`
- Calling `t.area()`
- In the area method - `self` is still of type `Tire` as seen in (*)
- Inside `area` - `self.__perimeter()` is called thus calling `_Circle__perimeter`

Comment: I think there's some part left out in your answer in the end

Comment: @ghost That part does not need to be there, sorry! - Because area is not private, it just accesses the private method of `Circle` (`__perimeter`) which by definition is `_Circle__perimeter`  - instead of `__perimeter` in the area method we can use `p = self._Circle__perimeter()`

Comment: So in `self.__perimeter()`, does `self` get resolved to `Circle` or `Tire`? And like how is that decided?

Comment: @ghost The type of `self` is `Tire` - However, when calling `self.__perimeter()` we do not 'go back' to the class of tire just to get the perimeter, but because we inherit from Circle we find the last method called `__perimeter` and run it - thus calling the `perimeter` method of circle, not tire. I will elaborate more in the answer